# One Stored procedure used for different calls from front end

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

Is it possible to create a single stored procedure that could perform 3 or more different searches? For example:

```
    WHERE 
    (AccountNumber= @AccountNumber)                                  and
    (@RoutingNumber = null)  or  ( RoutingNumber = @RoutingNumber)   and
    (@PolicyNumber = null)   or  (PolicyNumber = @PolicyNumber)      and
    (@PaymentAmount = null)  or  ( PaymentAmount = @PaymentAmount)   and
    (@StartDate = null) or (PostingDate >= @StartDate)  and
    (@EndDate = null)  or (PostingDate <= @EndDate)
```

so in this example every parameter is optional except for AccountNumber.

I want to be able to perform the following possible searches based on the input coming from UI. 
1) AccountNumber by itself. 
2) AccountNumber and StartDate and EndDate.
3) AccountNumber and PaymentAmount.

Now I know I can do this with 3 unique stored procedures but can it be accomplished with only one ?

Comment: have you tried your above?  aside from `@param = null` probably needing to be `@param is null` it looks fine-ish.  You will likely, maybe, eventually, run into some parameter sniffing issues but those can be solved as well

Comment: what you have written should work (syntax aside). I have used this technique before

Answer (score 0):

You can use Transact-SQL(T-SQL) to create if statements in the stored procedure. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx

Example query:

```
IF(@RoutingNumber IS NOT NULL)
   BEGIN
        //Put your query in here with the Routing number.
   END
ELSE IF (@StartDate IS NOT NULL AND @EndDate IS NOT NULL)
   BEGIN
        //put query in here with Start/End Date
   END
```

Etc....
Then inside of your C# code, you can simply use if/elses to determine if the form is filled out and just set the variables accordingly. The Stored Proc will do the rest.

Comment: will work but you will have to endure some duplication which might be a problem if the rest of the query is complex

Comment: @Banners Very true, but the alternative is simply having the other Stored procs like he mentioned he didn't want to happen.

Comment: I think his original suggestion is sound and would have no duplication (but looks a little messy). Perhaps to remove unnecessary duplication in your answer you could use a CTE for the bulk of the query and then select from the CTE and add the where clauses in each IF block. Might have to watch out for bad query plans from SQL